# download api for JQuery Dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I only need the dialog bog in jquery-ui library, so I do not want to download the entire package (from http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

. Is there a way to selectively get only the stuff that is needed to render the dialog box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link with the selection you need:

http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.9.2&components=1111101000010100000000000000000000

The **Dialog** Widget requires the **UI Core**, **Draggable** and **Resizable** Interactions, and the **Button** Widget.

Thats the minimum configuration possible.